# Python using sum() in a user made list

Tags: python, list, sum, average, user-input

So, the part of this project I cannot get to work is the `sum()` function.
It works during:

```
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    b = sum(a)
    print b
```

But in my program, I have a user created list and the `sum()` keeps getting an error. `len()` works, but I also need the sum to obtain an average.

```
     namelist = []              
     agelist = []

     while True:
        name = raw_input("Enter a name or type Exit to end data entry: ")
        namelist.append(name)

        if name == "Exit":      #creates an exit point from data entry 
            break

        age = raw_input("How old is " + name + "? ")
        agelist.append(age)

    lenage = len(agelist)
    sumage = sum(agelist)   #here is the problem -<<
    avgage = sumage / lenage

    print avgage
```

How can I get the sumage to work?
Is it not working because I did not define how long the list is?

Comment: You should transform the age from str to int

Comment: cast to `int` !

Answer (score 3):

The variable `age` has type string, so you need to convert it to an integer:

```
agelist.append(int(age))
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks!  It worked!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that `agelist` is a list of strings (inputs from the user) and before you can "add" those inputs you need to convert them either to an integer number or (probably) to a floating number (depending on what kind of average you want: an integer or floating point in Python 2):

```
sumage = sum(map(int, agelist)) # OR, replace int with float
```